# Delphi JEDI installer build 4197 does not recognize Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, jedi

After having installed XE2 I felt it would be a good idea to update Jedi JCL/JVCL

However, the installer does not recognize/show Delphi 2007 as an option any longer, only Delphi 2010 and XE2

Any way to fix that? I am guess it uses registry somehow?

Comment: YOu reinstalled JCL then JVCL?  They are separate installers, so you should specify what you did exactly. Where did you get the update?  Latest JCL & JVCL definitely supports delphi 2007.

Comment: Downloaded 3.45 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%203/JVCL%203.45/ and then tried to run install.bat for JCL

Anyhow, same problem with old installer. Somehow Delphi 2007 has gotten invisible to the JEDI JCL+JVCL installer.

Comment: The JCL 2.3.1.4197 build from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/ definitely supports D2007 and XE2. I have both installed and it correctly found them.  Not tried JVCL, though.

Comment: I think the explanation simply is Delphi 2007 has gotten invisible which is quite odd. Under all circumstances, the installer does not list Delphi 2007 any longer :(

Comment: Okay, I think I solved it like this: Backup'ed my old Jedi folder and renamed it. Then installed for XE2 from same folder as old was. Then renamed it. Renamed old folder back... Then copy/replaced new files into it.

Comment: Not sure I can understand what you did there Tom, sounds weird.

Comment: At first I tried to simply replace the old folder with the new JCL+JVCL leaving none of the source etc. old files (but still keep the BPLs of course in the respective Delphi's BPL dirs) and then install for XE2. However, that gave build errors with missing files in Delphi 2007 when I compiled projects that used JCL/JVCL. Therefore I had to think of a solution that would install correctly into XE2 (still keeping the same path that other Delphis use) but still making sure it would compile in .e.g Delphi 2007 when using the JCL and JVCL. That's why I resorted to a quite convoluted solution :)

Comment: Another reason I have seen why the Jedi installer doesn't work is on some 64 bit Windows systems, even running Clean.bad didn't work.  I have had to resort to manually compiling and installing packages on some systems.  Check the Jedi newsgroups for a big discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with the file you linked. JCL installer 2.31 is not detecting my Delphi 2007 IDE.  I have XE, XE2, 7, and 2007 and it will not recognize 2007 when I unzip and run the installer.

The Solution on my system was simple: Run `clean.bat`, and try the JCL install again.

Your suggestion of wiping the folder out and replacing it with a clean fresh copy, combined with running clean, and with deleting all existing JCL/JVCL bpls from your BPL folders, might be required too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was unsure what "clean" did and I did not want to risk "destroying" my Delphi 2007 and Delphi 2010 installation. I will bookmark this URL for when XE3 arrives :) Hopefully, by then, this will not be an issue! (Crossing fingers!)

Comment: I've posted some discussion on the jedi newsgroups and we'll try to make sure the next release installs cleanly.

Comment: I've started encountering this again with latest subversion repo version of JCL 2.3, in August 2012.

Comment: Does JEDI integrates with Delphi XE2? If yes, could you tell me how?

Comment: Latest Jedi VCL and JCL works fine with XE2. Just download it and install it.  :-)